# Serve images from an alternate location without exposing the location using url re-write

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

On my asp.net site running in IIS7 I want any images, css and scripts `(\.js|\.css|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$` on the HOME page to be loaded from a sub-domain, but for reasons I won’t go into I want them to appear to come from the original source location.

For example an image on the home page with a source of

```
http(s)://www.mysite.com/some-directory/image.gif
```

should actually be served from

```
http(s)://hidden.mysite.com/some-directory/image.gif
```

but as far as the requesting browser is concerned it should appear to come from the original source location.

Any scripts coming from `googleapis.xxx` should be excluded, as should any images from `/images(.*)`

Can this be achieved with url rewrite rules, if so how?

Comment: No reply, have I asked for something that's not possible?

Comment: This is certainly possible. Have you done something so far with the rewrite module or ARR?